# How to make rba feature work during box-shadow editing with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet

I'm trying to make this:

```
$(".selector").css({
  "box-shadow": "4px 4px 4px 4px rgba(#000, 0.3)",
 });
```

but it is not working and when I remove the 'rgba' and add a normal color (just `#000` for example) it works nice, I need to add some opacity to the shadow but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#000` is hex.

If you provide rgb values correctly it works for me!

```
 $(".selector").css({
   "box-shadow": "4px 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ns60fh4y/